# How can I print the string of a parameter from a property?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

Let's say I have this custom property `fu3dm_model_gender`: `bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Gender", description="Choose model's gender", items= [('OP1', "Male", ""), ('OP2', "Female", "")], default='OP1')` and I want to print the string of name parameter. How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

Actually, my property is part of an operator. In the following example I'd like to get the string of `name` parameter and display it where the three X's (XXX) are:

```
class fu3dm_WM_OT_Model_Prefs_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.fu3dm_model_prefs"
    bl_label = "Model Preferences"
    bl_description = "..."

    fu3dm_model_gender : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Gender", description="Choose model's gender", items= [('OP1', "Male", ""), ('OP2', "Female", "")], default='OP1')

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
        bpy.ops.wm.fu3dm_model_prefs('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

    def draw(self, context):

        layout = self.layout

    # BODY PREFS BOX - START
        box = layout.box()
        col = box.column()

        row = col.split()
        row.label(text=XXX)
        row.prop(self, "fu3dm_model_gender", text="")
    # BODY PREFS BOX - END

    def execute(self, context):
        pass
        return {"FINISHED"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Once registered you can use `bl_rna.properties` to access the name, its type, the items, the description etc... I'd suggest use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to test:

```
>>> test_items = [
...     ("RED", "Red", "", 1),
...     ("GREEN", "Green", "", 2),
...     ("BLUE", "Blue", "", 3),
...     ("YELLOW", "Yellow", "", 4),
... ] 

>>> bpy.types.Scene.my_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Foo", items=test_items)
>>> bpy.types.Scene.bl_rna.properties['my_enum'].name
'Foo'
>>> bpy.types.Scene.bl_rna.properties['my_enum'].enum_items[0]
<bpy_struct, EnumPropertyItem("RED")>
>>> bpy.types.Scene.bl_rna.properties['my_enum'].enum_items[0].name
'Red'
```

In case of an operator property, I'd suggest read the values from the operators annotation dict:

```
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    
    my_prop: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="foo")

    def execute(self, context):
        
        # via bl_rna
        print (self.properties.bl_rna.properties['my_prop'].name)
        
        # using annotations
        print (self.__annotations__.items())
        print (self.__annotations__['my_prop'][1]['name'])
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Hm... I didn't get it!!! Maybe I described it wrong. Can you please take a look on my question again? I updated it...

Comment: Yep, your description was not precise enough @SimonetosTheGreek

Comment: Yes I am sorry!!! So, if you have some time more, some clarifications so to understand 100% what I am learning and not just copying code. When do we use the `bl_rna` way? In `self.__annotations__['my_prop'][1]['name']` why do we use `1` and not `0`since `name` is the first parameter?

Comment: Basically a python question - the second item is dict we are looking for. Recommend make yourself familiar with [dir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) -> `print(dir(self.__annotations__['my_prop']))` @SimonetosTheGreek

Comment: Thank you for your time!!! :)

Comment: You're welcome @SimonetosTheGreek